# Tabbed view, Why it's not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying this simple code,but it works only with page 1 and 2, for 3 it shows blank. I can't find out what's the problem, please help!

```
<div id="allTabs">
    <input type="button" value="Page 1" name="b1" onclick='change("page1");'/> 
    <input type="button" value="Page 2" name="b2" onclick='change("page2");' />
    <input type="button" value="Page 3" name="b3" onclick='change("page3");' />

    <div id="page1" >This is page 1 </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display: none"> This is page 2 </div>
    <div id="page3" style="display: none"> This is page 3 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     function change(pageId) {
          var f=document.getElementById('page1');
          var h=document.getElementById('page2');
          var k=document.getElementById('page3')

          if(pageId=="page1") {
                f.style.display= 'block';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.diplay= 'none';
          }
         if(pageId=="page2") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'block';
                k.style.diplay= 'none';
          }
         if(pageId=="page3") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.diplay= 'block';
          }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo you misspelled `display` as `diplay` in your ***third condition***

```js
function change(pageId) {
          var f=document.getElementById('page1');
          var h=document.getElementById('page2');
          var k=document.getElementById('page3');

          if(pageId=="page1") {
                f.style.display= 'block';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.diplay= 'none';
          }
         if(pageId=="page2") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'block';
                k.style.display= 'none';
          }
  debugger;
         if(pageId=="page3") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.display= 'block';
          }
      }
```

```html
<div id="allTabs">
    <input type="button" value="Page 1" name="b1" onclick='change("page1");'/> 
    <input type="button" value="Page 2" name="b2" onclick='change("page2");' />
    <input type="button" value="Page 3" name="b3" onclick='change("page3");' />

    <div id="page1" >This is page 1 </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display: none"> This is page 2 </div>
    <div id="page3" style="display: none"> This is page 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a silly spelling mistake. `diplay` instead of `display`

Working Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNNgBO

```
<div id="allTabs">
    <input type="button" value="Page 1" name="b1" onclick='change("page1");'/> 
    <input type="button" value="Page 2" name="b2" onclick='change("page2");' />
    <input type="button" value="Page 3" name="b3" onclick='change("page3");' />

    <div id="page1" >This is page 1 </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display: none"> This is page 2 </div>
    <div id="page3" style="display: none"> This is page 3 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     function change(pageId) {
          var f=document.getElementById('page1');
          var h=document.getElementById('page2');
          var k=document.getElementById('page3')

          if(pageId=="page1") {
                f.style.display= 'block';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.display= 'none';
          }
         if(pageId=="page2") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'block';
                k.style.display= 'none';
          }
         if(pageId=="page3") {
                f.style.display= 'none';
                h.style.display= 'none';
                k.style.display= 'block';
          }
      }
</script>
```